# How can I contain math.random div placement within window?

Tags: javascript, html, random

I've generated some simple javascript which randomly scatters divs across upon every page refresh.

I've noticed that occasionally one of the divs will be placed outside the window boundaries.

I just wanted to find a way to always contain the randomly placed images within the window. 
Thank you for any help or suggestions in advance!

currently i'm just using this javascript:

```
$(".pstn").each(function(i,el){
var tLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),
    tTop  = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
$(el).css({position:'absolute', left: tLeft, top: tTop});
});
```

Comment: Some code would really help answering your question. It all depends on how you give unique positions

Comment: thanks @raam86, hopefully that helps. i can attempt a jsfiddle if that's easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the max `left`

`var maxLeft = $(window).innerWidth() - $(el).innerWidth();`

and the max `top`

`var maxTop = $(window).innerHeight() - $(el).innerHeight();`

Then you random it:

```
var tLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxLeft),
    tTop  = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxTop);
```

Comment: Change `$(el).innerWidth()` and `$(el).innerHeight()` to `$(el).find('img').height()` AND `curWidth = $(el).find('img').width()` respectively

Comment: thank you both a heap, both scripts work fantastically. for now i've decided the following is most suitable for my needs as it allows the divs to appear partially outside the window.

cheers again!

`var maxLeft = $(window).innerWidth() - $(el).innerWidth() - 100;
 var maxTop = $(window).innerHeight() - $(el).innerHeight() - 100;`

Comment: @AndrewIreland If the answer helped you you should choose it as best answer by clicking the tick under the vote counter